# Quicker way of adding x to every second element in all nested arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a nested array in ruby, similar to the one below, but with quite a few more nested arrays.

```
arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Is there a way to get every second element within the nested array, and add x to that element? I have used the code below, but if there is a quicker way I'd love to know.

```
x = 5
arr[0][1], arr[1][1], arr[2][1] = arr[0][1]+x, arr[1][1]+x, arr[2][1]+x
```

I *have* tried to use `arr.map!{|f,l| [f, l + 1]}`, but I get the result `arr == [[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]]`

EDIT:

So the outcome should be `arr == [[1,2+x,3],[4,5+x,6],[7,8+x,9]]`

Comment: try flattening it first, `flat_arr = arr.flatten`, and go from there

Comment: Please edit to show your desired result. Is it `[[1+5,2,3+5],[4+5,5,6+5],[7+5,8,9+5]]` or `[[1,2+5,3],[4,5+5,6],[7,8+5,9]]` or `[[1+5,2,3+5],[4,5+5,6],[7+5,8,9+5]]` or something else? Usually when one says "every second element" or "every other element", it begins with the first element. Since you have stated otherwise, presumably `arr` can have an arbitrary number of elements (arrays) and each element of `arr` (an array) can have an arbitrary number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you find yourself writing that kind of code over and over, you should look to use a loop! Ruby commonly uses [iterators](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/blocks/iterators.html) for performing looping. [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-each) is an iterator which loops over an Array, and lets you operate on each element one at a time.

Since you know that you want to add x to the second element in each, this is trivially:

```
arr.each {|e| e[1] += x }
```

This mutates `arr` (and `arr`'s subarrays) in place. If you want to return a mutated copy, you would use `map`, which is like `each` except the return value is the *output* of the block, rather than the *input* to it.

```
# First we clone each subarray with Array#dup, then we iterate the
# clones, adding x to the second element. Because we're using `map`
# the result will be a new array, rather than the original arr, leaving
# the original unmodified.
new_arr = arr.map(&:dup).each {|e| e[1] += x }
```

Comment: Oooh, righto thanks. I was overthinking the problem  Thanks for the quick reply too!!

Comment: If my reply answered your question, please click the check mark next to the answer to indicate that it's the desired answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

You're close! You can use `map` to loop through each sub-array and the ruby `+=` operator to add `x` to the second element of each. The trick with `map` is that you'll need to return the *entire sub-array* in each loop, which would look like:

```rb
arr.map { |a| a[1] += x; a }
#=> [[1, 7, 3], [4, 10, 6], [7, 13, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
x = 5

arr.map { |a, b, c| [a, b + x, c] }
#=> [[1, 7, 3], [4, 10, 6], [7, 13, 9]]
```

Note that [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-map) returns a new array. If you want to modify the existing array,  there's `map!`.